# perl SOAP::Lite proxy authentification

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume some SOAP Web Service from perl with SOAP::Lite.
my script looks like :

```
use SOAP::Lite;
my $url1 = http://myUsername:myPassword@myProxyServer:port;
my $url2 = https: //myUsername:myPassword@server.wsdl;

print SOAP::Lite
    -> proxy($url1)
    -> service($url2)
    ->myMethod("foo", "bar");
```

and i get this error :

> Server description `https://myUsername:myPassword@server.wsdl` can't
>   be loaded: 500 Can't connect to
>   `http://myUsername:myPassword@myProxyServer:port`

.
The $url1 and $url2 urls are correct and the myMethod method exist in wsdl file.

Any help will be apreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

`SOAP::Lite` cannot consume WSDL as far as I know.

If you want to use `SOAP::Lite`, you will need to read the WSDL yourself, and figure out the correct value to use for `$url2`

Or you could take a look at building a client based around `XML::Compile`, which can process WSDL and allow you to call a service based on it.